# Segfault that I can not figure out the cause of

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

No matter what I try to find the segfault I can not figure out what is causing it. I tried using GDB but it would say segfault immediately when trying to run it even when breaking it into smaller chunks to run. I even put print statements as the first line of the main function to print the command line arguments but it gave an immediate seg fault. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
typedef struct numbers {
  int lineNum;
  int sum;
  char status[10];
}numbers;
// function declaration
int calculateDivisors(int num);

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    //declare variables
    int x;
    int y;
    int i, j;
    int numStructs;
    char histChar;

    //initialize x and y to the first and second values
    if (argc == 4){
      x = atoi(argv[1]);
      y = atoi(argv[2]);
      histChar = atoi(argv[3]);
    }
    //check to make sure command line arguments are used
    if (argc < 4){
      printf("Too few arguments.\n");
      printf("Correct usage: ./a.out integer integer character");
    }
    if (argc > 4){
      printf("Too many arguments.\n");
      printf("Correct usage: ./a.out integer integer character");
    }

    //checking for reasonableness of inputs
    if((x < 2)){
      printf("Sorry, the lower bound must be 2 or greater\n");
      printf("Please enter the lower value: ");
      scanf("%d", &x);
      printf("Please enter the upper value: ");
      scanf("%d", &y);
    }
    if((y < x)){
      printf("Sorry, the first value must be less than the second.\n");
      printf("Please enter the lower value: ");
      scanf("%d", &x);
      printf("Please enter the upper value: ");
      scanf("%d", &y);
    }
    numStructs = y - x + 2;
    //dynamically allocate space for the array of structures
    numbers *arr = malloc(numStructs * sizeof(numbers));
    //for loop to pass numbers to the function Calculate divisors
    for(i = x; i <= y; ++i){
      for(j = 0; j < numStructs; ++j){
      //if else if, else statement to decide if the number is perfect or not
      if (calculateDivisors(i) == i){
          arr[j].lineNum = i;
          arr[j].sum = calculateDivisors(i);
          strcpy("Perfect", arr[j].status);
      }
      else if(calculateDivisors(i) >= i){
          arr[j].lineNum = i;
          arr[j].sum = calculateDivisors(i);
          strcpy("Abundant", arr[j].status);
      }
      else if(calculateDivisors(i) <= i){
          arr[j].lineNum = i;
          arr[j].sum = calculateDivisors(i);
          strcpy("Deficient", arr[j].status);
      }
    }
  }
    //for loop to print everything
    for (i = 0; i < numStructs; ++i){
      printf("%d is %s", arr[i].lineNum, arr[i].status);
      i = 0;
      while (i < arr[i].sum){
        printf("%c", histChar);
      }
    }


    return 0;
  }

//function implementation
int calculateDivisors(int num){
  int i;
  int sum;
  for (i = 1; i < (num / 2); ++i){
    if (num % 1 == 0){
      if ((num / i) == i){
        sum += i;
      }
      else {
        sum = sum + i + (num / i);
      }
    }
  }
  return (sum);
}
```

Comment: Should `histChar = atoi(argv[3]);` be `histChar = argv[3][0]);` ?

Comment: I do not think so, doing that gives me the "passing argument 1 makes pointer from integer without a cast" error

Comment: There isn't any "passing argument 1" in what I wrote. It's unclear what `char histChar` is for, because you only use it once, to output in a loop.

Comment: Aside: `if (num % 1 == 0)` is always `true`.

Comment: sorry that was when I tried it with sscanf I tried with atoi as well and it was a similar error. histChar is used to make a histogram through that loop of what the divisors of the number input add up to.

Comment: `histChar = argv[3][0];` does not use `atoi` or `sscanf`. The closing parenthesis was a typo,

Comment: Thank you for your assistance but I actually found the issue. My strcpy commands had the parameters in the wrong places

Comment: Good but `if (num % 1 == 0)` is still always `true`.